# Guessing a secret number (computer vs computer) - AI

Tags: c++, numbers, artificial-intelligence

I have a problem with my code for guessing a secret number. I want to make a game just computer guesses and answers. I tried to write the code but the result is infinite looping.

This is my code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int lowest = 0;
  int highest = 9;
  srand(time(0));
  int number;
  number = rand() % 9+1;
  int guess;
  guess = rand() % 9+1;
  do {
      if (number){
        switch(number)
               {
                          case 1:
                                 if(guess>lowest)
                                lowest=guess;
                                do {
                                   guess=rand()%9 +1;
                                   }while(guess<lowest || guess>highest);
                               break;
                           case 2:
                                if(guess<highest)
                               highest=guess;
                               do  {
                                   guess=rand()%9 +1;
                                   }while(guess<lowest || guess>highest);
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                  cout<<"\n\n\aHA! I got it right"<< endl;
                                 break;
               }

        if (guess < number){
              cout << "Your guess is less than secret number"<<endl ;
              }
        else if (guess > number){
              cout << "Your guess is high than secret number"<<endl ;
              }
        else
              cout << "Your guess is right!" << endl;

      }
  } while (guess != number);

  return 0;
}
```

Please help me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Check the value you're testing in the switch statement. Unless the guess is 1,2, or 3, the code never enters the switch and never picks a new number. Even if you do get a 1,2, or 3, the result is almost certainly not what you have in mind.

Comment: What do you think `switch(number)` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're confused about how a switch statement works. As written, your code looks at `number` and does something if number is `1` (in which case it executes case 1), or if `number` is `2`, or `3`. If `number` is not one of these options, it does nothing. I suspect what you WANT is to replace the switch with an `if-else-if-else-if-...` block. It seems you're struggling with fundamental syntax, in particular control flow. To get more information you should check out chapter 5 of this site: http://www.learncpp.com/. I think that'll help you better understand what your code is doing.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, williamg. I go the right answer.